# Низкий пошиб

Tags: фразеология

И еще один вопрос у меня по фразеологии. А именно о выражении "низкого пошиба". О каком пошибе идет речь, что это вообще такое и почему он низкий?
Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пошиб - это стиль, манера, обычно в отношении картин и других предметов искусства.
Низкий пошиб - это предмет низкого, дурного вкуса, "лубок".

*Пошиб. [...]имеет свою номинативную специфику слово пошиб — соотносительно с основными словами своего синонимического ряда — стиль, манера. Слово пошиб в древнерусском языке служило для обозначения стиля иконописания. К XVIII в. оно выходит из литературного употребления и возрождается лишь в 50—60-х годах XIX в. в более общем и широком значении — `стиль чего-нибудь'. Тут смысловая сфера экспрессивного синонима выходит за пределы бытовых значений и употреблений основного, опорного слова небольшой синонимической группы, связанной со словом стиль.*

*И. Т. Кокорев прямо предлагал заменить заимствованное слово стиль народно-русским пошиб (Кокорев 1858, ч. 3, с. 325—326). Но в слове пошибразвились своеобразные смысловые оттенки, сближающие его не только со словами стиль, манера, характер, но и со словами типа повадка, замашки и т. п. Ср. у Бодуэна де Куртенэ в дополнениях к словарю Даля: молодец нововременного пошиба; у Достоевского в «Бесах»: отставной армейский капитан нахального пошиба; у Тургенева в «Нови»: «Нежданов тотчас почувствовал, что они оба, эта угрюмая девушка и он, — одних убеждений и одного пошиба». В черновых набросках этого романа, о Паклине: «Как будто имеет пошиб политика, но это только по наружности...» (Mazon A. L'élaboration d'un roman de Tourgenev // Revue des études slaves. Paris, 1925, t. 5, f. 1—2, с. 91).*
(Основные типы лексических значений слова // Виноградов. Избр. тр.: Лексикология и лексикография, с. 174—175).
В. В. Виноградов. История слов, 2010

Answer (score 2):

Слово "пошиб" происходит от глагола "шибать" со значением бить, бросать; родственные слова: ушибить, расшибить, также ошибиться (неправильно бросить, промахнуться).
Можно предположить, что пошиб — это изначально манера, стиль броска, а потом уже просто стиль, манера.

[Можно и ошибиться... | relga.ru](http://www.relga.ru/Environ/WebObjects/tgu-www.woa/wa/Main?textid=1716&level1=main&level2=articles)